# modular reduction using solinas prime

Tags: elliptic-curves, implementation, modular-arithmetic

I want to perform a modular reduction using Solinas prime value as q = 2^383-2^33+1. How can I efficiently compute it taking advantage of q being Solinas prime?

Answer (score 2):

The rough idea is:

1. start with the highest non-zero word,
2. multiply each non-zero term in the Solinas number (for example, -1 at 33'rd bit and 1 at lowest bit)
3. subtract the multiplied term from the number twice - the second time is to ensure any carry in the highest non-zero word is cleared.
4. repeat the process for the next highest word until the number is less than the modulus.

I've an [implementation](https://github.com/dannyniu/MySuiteA/blob/1875b7503ccce309474bdfaf2efae50f8658bb94/src/2-ec/curve-secp256r1.c#L17) of this you can reference, it's written for the modulus of the P-256 curve.